# XCode 4 beeps when entering brackets

Tags: xcode, configuration

How can I turn this behavoir off?

It happens when you enter a close bracket without a matching open bracket.  Which is annoying because I do that all the time.  I don't need xcode beeping at me (under any circustances).

(Of course I always go back and put the opening bracket in, I guess this makes me wierd, but my mind just works that way, and I don't need xcode nagging me about it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto Xode-> Preferences-> Text Editing-> Code completion
in this u can then untick option "balance brackets in objective-c method calls"

It shold help you. But I suggest you to keep this option enable.
Also in "General" tab of Xcode preference you can set "Play Sound"(first option) enable/disable.

Comment: There is no longer a sound option on the general tab, but there are sound options under the Behaviours tab and I have them all turned off.

Turning off the bracket completions options does not stop the sound.

This seems pretty well baked into Xcode somewhere I just can't find. It's not an OSX function, I tested that.

Comment: I have turned off the system wide error beep, that seems to have done it.